How to integrate AJAX with a PHP variable or a div?
Greeting everyone.
I have such code:
<a href="<?=ROOT?>notifications">
    <span style="display: inline-block;position: relative;">
        <img src="<?=ROOT?>notification.svg" style="width:25px;height:25px;float:right;margin-top: 20px;margin-left:0px;">
        <?php 
            $notif = check_notifications();
        ?>
        <?php if($notif > 0): ?>
            <div  style="background-color: #2e2e2e;color: white;position: absolute;right:-15px;margin-top:10px;
            width:15px;height: 15px;border-radius: 50%;padding: 4px;text-align:center;font-size: 14px;"><?= $notif ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </span>
</a>

And the thing is that I also have a service worker, which causes the variable $notif, which displays the number of notifications, to be shown falsely, as the service worker saves the pages I visited and the $notif values that were displayed when visiting any page. The point is that this $notif is displayed on the top navigation bar, and every time I switch between tabs, it changes. I think it's possible to write an AJAX function here to update $notif or its div block every 2 seconds? Or are there other options that I can implement?

Welcome to SO! It is unclear which part of the implementation you have a problem with. Assuming that the notifications number is stored on the backend, you must call the backend to mark a notification as seen (or decrease the number of notifications) and request the current number of notifications to update your UI. If this assumption is correct, at which stage do you have a problem?
